# Postman generated code get {"error":"invalid_client"} on C# console

Tags: c#, postman

I have copied paste "get token" request form Postman code generator to C#
I get the token in Postman but on Visual Studio it gives:

> {"error":"invalid_client"}

while all details are same.

Its now with RestClient. I would like to convert it to HttpClient and check it out. Appreciate help on that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;

namespace ConsoleApp_postman_copyPaste_test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Direct from Postman
            var client = new RestClient("https://label.xxx.xxx.net/mytoken++++/api/label/v1/auth/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "0000f-c111-41b2-a90b-959aa839db65");
            request.AddParameter("Username", "aaa19 llcfrt");
            request.AddParameter("Password", "gb&8HJtyKB");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

            //up to here from postman

            Trace.TraceInformation(response.Content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have added grant_type and client_id as headers, instead of request parameters.

Comment: tried that , not working. The code is taken form Postman, but actually on postman , these are inserted as body (and is working smoothly) but I am not sure how to implement in on the code.

Comment: Does the request works fine on Postman?

Comment: works very well , yes - i get json with the token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the request a HTTP Post

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Direct from Postman
            var client = new RestClient("https://label.xxx.xxx.net/mytoken++++/api/label/v1/auth/token");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "0000f-c111-41b2-a90b-959aa839db65");
            request.AddParameter("Username", "aaa19 llcfrt");
            request.AddParameter("Password", "gb&8HJtyKB");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

            //up to here from postman

            Trace.TraceInformation(response.Content);
        }
```